# Function Constructor vs eval

Tags: javascript, function

I stumbled upon this on [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) regarding `Function`

> The Function constructor creates a new Function object. Calling the
>   constructor directly can create functions dynamically, but suffers
>   from security and similar (but far less significant) performance
>   issues to eval. However, unlike eval, the Function constructor creates
>   functions which execute in the global scope only.

Can someone explain me what is function constructor and what is eval? Or in other words, can someone explain me the above statement in advance?

Comment: Slightly tongue in cheek, they are both similar in that you should never use them :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means essentially what `new Function('...')` and `eval('...')` work in a similar way, in the sense that they will evaluate the string in the argument as a JS expression. However, they have different scoping rules:

- `new Function()` only has access to the global scope
- `eval()` has access to the local scope

An example will be this:

- You create a function, say `f`, which is `new Function('console.log(x)')`, and then invoke it. Regardless of which scope `f()` is called, it will always log the value of `x` on the global scope
- You have `eval('console.log(x)')`. The value of `x` is dependent on the scope `eval()` is in:

```js
const x = 'global x';
const f = new Function('console.log(x)');

f(); // logs 'global x'
eval('console.log(x)'); // logs 'global x'

// Let's create a function scope
function test() {
  const x = 'local x';
  const f = new Function('console.log(x)');

  f(); // logs 'global x'
  eval('console.log(x)'); // logs 'local x';
}
test();
```